# Is this a nod to new 52 or just a coincidence?

Tags: reference, arrowverse, supergirl

I saved this screenshot from the 5th episode of season 1 of Supergirl and I was wondering, is the a nod to the new 52 or just a coincidence?

[image]

Comment: In what sense do you think it might be "a nod"?

Comment: I think this is The US Bank Tower in LA, or perhaps a CGI replica of it. (It appears on *Independence Day*, if I'm not mistaken.) How does it relate to the New 52? **EDIT**: Oh, I see, a zoom in reveals a faint 52 pattern there, similar to the 12 on the [Bank Tower's roof](http://footage.framepool.com/shotimg/qf/181058510-u%20s%20-bank-tower-landing-pad-los-angeles-logo.jpg).

Comment: Well the image was messed up. The number 52 is on the helipad on top of building

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely a nod and not a coincidence, simply because there are too many such cameos by the number **52** in all Berlanti DC comic TV shows.

The number shows up in *Arrow*, *The Flash* and, as noted by the OP, also in *Supergirl* - and will therefore probably also pop up in the upcoming *DC's Legends of Tomorrow*.

In numerous episodes on all shows - it might even be worth a follow up question to determine, if actually in every single one - the number **52** makes its cameo appearance, either

- verbally, e.g. as a number in an address ("corner 52nd and ...") or - in *Arrow* Season 2 as the callsign of Officer Lance ("Delta Charlie Five-Two" = "DC-52"), or
- visually, as shown in the example picture. In *Arrow*, *Channel 52* seems to be the Star City local news channel (the channel itself being a nod to the New 52), but it also appears on *The Flash*,

  > at least one of their news choppers does, as Barry runs across its blades in the season 2 winter finale (*The Flash - 2x09*).

The characters themselves share some characteristics from their *New 52* counterparts (while of course ignoring others to make it fresh and fitting for the medium).

> [The New 52 is] the closest to our origin story and what we're doing. [Grant "Barry Allen" Gustin in an interview](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=54270)

So while I could not (yet?) find a quote by anyone from the production actually confirming those numerous occurences to **be** *nods*, they are way too numerous to be conincidental, so the *MythBusters* would probably call it **Plausible**, I'd go further and say: *most probably **yes***.